# Android: Refresh cursorloader from a second activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-cursorloader

Have a good day. I'm learning Android development so i'm creating a simple CRUD application, right now i have my main activity that has the listview (MarcaActivity) with the next code:

```
package com.example.crudapp.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.crudapp.MarcaCursorAdapter;
import com.example.crudapp.R;
import com.example.crudapp.cp.MarcaCP;

public class MarcaActivity extends Activity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

MarcaCursorAdapter crsAdap;
ListView lstMarcas;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_marca);

    lstMarcas = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstMarcas);
    lstMarcas.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MarcaActivity.this, MarcaDetailActivity.class);
            Uri todoUri = Uri.parse(MarcaCP.CONTENT_URI + "/" + arg3);
            i.putExtra("DET", todoUri);
            i.putExtra("ACTION", "EXISTING");

            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    fillData();
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.insertMnu:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MarcaDetailActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("ACTION", "NEW");
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

@Override
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    /*switch (item.) {
    case DELETE_ID:
      AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
          .getMenuInfo();
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(MarcaCP.CONTENT_URI + "/"
          + info.id);
      getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
      fillData();
      return true;
    }*/
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
  }

private void fillData() {
    crsAdap = new MarcaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.template_marcas, null , 
            new String[]{MarcaCP.Marca.NOMBRE, MarcaCP.Marca.RANKING}, new int[]{R.id.nomMarca, R.id.rankMarca});

    lstMarcas.setAdapter(crsAdap);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.marca, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, MarcaCP.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{MarcaCP.Marca.ID, MarcaCP.Marca.NOMBRE, MarcaCP.Marca.CODIGO, MarcaCP.Marca.RANKING}, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    crsAdap.swapCursor(arg1);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    crsAdap.swapCursor(null);
} }
```

Then, i have the activity that manages the detail view where i can update or add items, called MarcaDetailActivity:

```
package com.example.crudapp.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.crudapp.MarcaCursorAdapter;
import com.example.crudapp.R;
import com.example.crudapp.cp.MarcaCP;

public class MarcaDetailActivity extends Activity {

MarcaCursorAdapter crsAdap;
private Integer idReg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detalle_marca);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras != null && extras.get("ACTION").equals("EXISTING"))  //Invocamos fillData
        fillData((Uri)extras.get("DET"));
    else
        cleanForm();

}

public void cleanForm() {
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.todo_edit_button)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.todo_insert_button)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void fillData(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MarcaCP.Marca.CODIGO,
            MarcaCP.Marca.CLASIFICACION, MarcaCP.Marca.NOMBRE, MarcaCP.Marca.RANKING};
    //builder.
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if(cur != null) {
        cur.moveToFirst();
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.detNombre)).setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MarcaCP.Marca.NOMBRE)));
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.detCodigo)).setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MarcaCP.Marca.CODIGO)));
        setIdReg(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(MarcaCP.Marca.ID)));
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.todo_edit_button)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.todo_insert_button)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        String clasif = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MarcaCP.Marca.CLASIFICACION));
        int rank = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(MarcaCP.Marca.RANKING));

        Spinner spRnk = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.detRanking));
        Spinner spClasf = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.detClasificacion));

        //Buscamos setear los spinners en sus valores
        for(short ps = 0; ps < spRnk.getCount(); ps++) {
            String tmpRnk = (String)spRnk.getItemAtPosition(ps);
            if(tmpRnk.equalsIgnoreCase("" + rank))
                spRnk.setSelection(ps);
        }

        //Buscamos setear los spinners en sus valores
        for(short ps = 0; ps < spClasf.getCount(); ps++) {
            String tmpClas = (String)spClasf.getItemAtPosition(ps);
            if(tmpClas.equalsIgnoreCase(clasif))
                spClasf.setSelection(ps);
        }

        cur.close();
    }
}

private boolean validate() {
    boolean res = true;

    return res;
}

public void guardar(View view) {
    if(validate()) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(MarcaCP.Marca.CLASIFICACION, (String)((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.detClasificacion)).getSelectedItem() );
        cv.put(MarcaCP.Marca.CODIGO, ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.detCodigo)).getText().toString() );
        cv.put(MarcaCP.Marca.NOMBRE, ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.detNombre)).getText().toString() );
        cv.put(MarcaCP.Marca.RANKING, Integer.parseInt("" + ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.detRanking)).getSelectedItem() ));

        getContentResolver().insert(MarcaCP.CONTENT_URI, cv);
    }

    Toast.makeText(MarcaDetailActivity.this, "Registro registrado",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Refrescamos el grid y cerramos la actividad
    //((MarcaActivity)this.getCallingActivity()).refrescarLista()
    //getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, MarcaActivity.class);

    this.finish();
}

public void regresar() {
    Intent i = new Intent(MarcaDetailActivity.this, MarcaActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("REFRESH", true);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void actualizar(View view) {
    if(validate()) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(MarcaCP.Marca.CLASIFICACION, (String)((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.detClasificacion)).getSelectedItem() );
        cv.put(MarcaCP.Marca.CODIGO, (String)((TextView)findViewById(R.id.detCodigo)).getText() );
        cv.put(MarcaCP.Marca.NOMBRE, (String)((TextView)findViewById(R.id.detNombre)).getText() );
        cv.put(MarcaCP.Marca.ID, getIdReg() );
        cv.put(MarcaCP.Marca.RANKING, Integer.parseInt("" + ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.detRanking)).getSelectedItem() ));

        getContentResolver().update(MarcaCP.CONTENT_URI, cv, null, null);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.marca, menu);
    return true;
}

public Integer getIdReg() {
    return idReg;
}

public void setIdReg(Integer idReg) {
    this.idReg = idReg;
} }
```

As you can see in the method guardar of MarcaDetailActivity, first i insert the item using my custom content provider, then i use Toast to show a confirm message, and finally finishing the activity, but when i do that, the listview isn't refreshed via the cursorloader. I read here (stackoverflow) and in other pages that i have to call

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LIST_ID, null, this);
```

But in all examples that i found all the stuff (inserting data in the database and refreshing the list) is in the same activity, but in this case i have an activity with the list and the second activity that inserts the item, so i think that i have to call restartLoader from my detail activity, but i don't know how to do that or if that's the right way to do this. I was thinking about saving a reference to the list activity in extras when i create the intent to call the detail activity and have a public method that calls restartLoader but i don't know if that is the best approach. What's the best way to refresh the cursor loader from my detail activity?

And there's my content provider, MarcaCP:

```
package com.example.crudapp.cp;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.example.crudapp.util.ConnHandler;

public class MarcaCP extends ContentProvider {

private static final int TODOS = 10;
private static final int TODO_ID = 20;

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://provider.marcacp/marcas");
private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static {
    sURIMatcher.addURI("provider.marcacp", "marcas", TODOS);
    sURIMatcher.addURI("provider.marcacp", "marcas" + "/#", TODO_ID);
}

public static class Marca {
    public static final String TABLA = "MARCA";
    public static final String ID = "_id";
    public static final String CODIGO = "codigo";
    public static final String NOMBRE = "nombre";
    public static final String CLASIFICACION = "clasificacion";
    public static final String RANKING = "ranking";
}

private ConnHandler conn;
SQLiteDatabase dbObj;

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    int rowsDeleted = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
    case TODOS:
      rowsDeleted = dbObj.delete(Marca.TABLA, selection, selectionArgs);
      break;
    case TODO_ID:
      String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
      if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
        rowsDeleted = dbObj.delete(Marca.TABLA,
            Marca.ID + " = " + id, 
            null);
      } else {
        rowsDeleted = dbObj.delete(Marca.TABLA,
           Marca.ID + " =" + id 
            + " and " + selection,
            selectionArgs);
      }
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsDeleted;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);

    long id = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
    case TODOS:
      id = dbObj.insert(Marca.TABLA, null, values);
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return Uri.parse("marca/" + id);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    conn = new ConnHandler(getContext());
    dbObj = conn.getDb();
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    // Uisng SQLiteQueryBuilder instead of query() method
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    checkColumns(projection);
    queryBuilder.setTables(Marca.TABLA);

    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);

    switch (uriType) {
    case TODOS:
      break;
    case TODO_ID:
        // Digamos para ver el detalle de un registro
        queryBuilder.appendWhere(Marca.ID + " = "
            + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URIx: " + uri);
      }


    Cursor cur = queryBuilder.query(dbObj, projection, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    return cur;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    int rowsUpdated = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
    case TODOS:
      rowsUpdated = dbObj.update(Marca.TABLA, 
          values, 
          selection,
          selectionArgs);
      break;
    case TODO_ID:
      String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
      if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
        rowsUpdated = dbObj.update(Marca.TABLA, 
            values,
            Marca.ID + " =" + id, 
            null);
      } else {
        rowsUpdated = dbObj.update(Marca.TABLA, 
            values,
            Marca.ID + " =" + id 
            + " and " 
            + selection,
            selectionArgs);
      }
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsUpdated;
}

private void checkColumns(String[] projection) {
    /*String[] available = { TodoTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY,
        TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY, TodoTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,
        TodoTable.COLUMN_ID };
    if (projection != null) {
      HashSet<String> requestedColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(projection));
      HashSet<String> availableColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(available));
      // Check if all columns which are requested are available
      if (!availableColumns.containsAll(requestedColumns)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown columns in projection");
      }
    }*/
  }   }
```

It's already registered in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider android:name=".cp.MarcaCP" android:authorities="provider.marcacp" />
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getContentResolver().notifyChange(MarcaCP.CONTENT_URI, null, false)` from the second activity before finishing it.

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't work, viewing the documentation it seems that i have to specify a ContentObserver.

Comment: It should work.  Loader is observing the changes.  Do not restart the loader, it should refresh itself.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, but maybe i have something wrong in my content provider because i see that it uses it's URI, i updated the main post with the code of MarcaCP and how i registered it in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Regards.

Comment: Right now i tried this: based on this link

http://komputercevapver.blogspot.com/2013/03/cursor-loader.html

i overrided the method onResume and there i call restartLoader to refresh the list when i finish my second activity:

@Override
  protected void onResume() {               
   // if you want to restart loader
         getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
         super.onResume();
 }

Comment: the notifyChange() code looks good.  The only difference from my code is I use notifyChange(uri, null, false) so that there is no attempt to sync (unless you have sync adapter to propagate the change to the server).  There should be no need to restartLoader() because loaders observe their URIs. Can you debug that notifyChange() is really called?  Can you also debug if onLoadFinished() is called after notifyChange()?  May be it is your custom cursor adapter that is doing something wrong? If notifyChange() and onLoadFinished() are called, can you debug your adapter?

Comment: Ok im gonna check it out. I imagine that when i debug the method query has to be called again right?

Comment: Yes, when the loader receives change signal from notifyChange() it should re-query the data

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late to answer this.

since in your ContentProvider, you have

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange
```

which is great and correct!

so there is no need to called
`getContentResolver().notifyChange(MarcaCP.CONTENT_URI, null, false)` from the second activity before finishing it.

the problem is that instead of using `getLoaderManager().initLoader`
which is deprecated and not life-cycled aware.

**try use**

```
LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader
```

this: is a class that maintains its own android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle and android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelStore. For instance, androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity or androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.
**so that when you pop back to the first activity and OnResume() called, there is no need to restart the loader again.**

**P.s. also a great reminder. Do not close any **cursor** related to the `onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)`
if doing so will also cause the loader won't update itself after data changed in DB.**